# python : COMERROR when reading file

Tags: python, pdf, powerpoint, comtypes

I'm using Windows and Jupyter to write python code, and when I'm using package comtypes.client, it is unstable, sometimes it works, sometimes it doesn't. What I'm doing is trying to convert pptx file to pdf file. Here is my code :

```
import comtypes.client

def PPTtoPDF(inputFileName, outputFileName, formatType = 32):
    powerpoint = comtypes.client.CreateObject("Powerpoint.Application")
    powerpoint.Visible = 1

    if outputFileName[-3:] != 'pdf':
        outputFileName = outputFileName + ".pdf"
    deck = powerpoint.Presentations.Open(inputFileName)
    deck.SaveAs(outputFileName, formatType) # formatType = 32 for ppt to pdf
    deck.Close()
    powerpoint.Quit()

PPTtoPDF('07-20 contact PPT.pptx','./Reports/07-20 contact result',32)
```

And the error is:

```
COMError: (-2147024894, 'The system cannot find the file specified.', (None, None, None, 0, None))
```

I don't think there's something wrong with this code, since it works well for several times, so maybe it is because of the computer environment or something else. Could any one tell me how I can make this code stable, or is there any better to convert PPTX to PDF in python?

Thank you all~

Comment: I think the major problem is because some parts of win32com don't work well on 64bit.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this juanbin?

Comment: No, I don't think there's a efficient way to transfer PPT to PDF in python right now on 64bit computer...

Comment: I have the same issue when I convert PPTX to PDF. The weird thing is opening PPTX first and enabling "Edit mode" fixes the issue, but disabling "Protected mode" in the powerpoint settings does not fix the issue.
So for me workaround:
1) open PPTX by double click
2)press "Enable Editing", close the file
3)run the script - works like a charm

Comment: `pip3 install pywinauto` updating to 0.6.8 fixed the issue

Answer (score 0):

I received the same error and I have a 64-bit Windows PC. My solution involved specifying the file path with:

```
# Open the ppt file path. sys.argv[1] is the ppt name.
mypath = os.path.abspath(__file__)
mydir = os.path.dirname(mypath)
file_input = os.path.join(mydir, sys.argv[1])

# create the pdf output file path and call your function 
file_output = os.path.join(mydir, sys.argv[1][:-4] + "pdf")
PPTtoPDF(file_input, file_output)
```

Answer (score 0):

If anyone still has problems with this error, what I did was manually change the input and output paths like this.

```
#the double quotes make it a single quote
inputFileName=inputFileName.replace("/","\\") 
outputFileName=outputFileName.replace("/","\\")
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead).

Answer (score 0):

I was with the same problem, and after much trial and error, I find it.

The object created from comtypes.client.CreateObject() need the absolute path to the file.

here's a way to solve it:

```
from os.path import abspath
import comtypes.client

def PPTtoPDF(inputFileName, outputFileName, formatType = 32):
    inputFileName = abspath(inputFileName) #Transform to Absolute Path
    outputFileName = abspath(outputFileName) #Transform to Absolute Path

    powerpoint = comtypes.client.CreateObject("Powerpoint.Application")
    powerpoint.Visible = 1

    if outputFileName[-3:] != 'pdf':
        outputFileName = outputFileName + ".pdf"

    deck = powerpoint.Presentations.Open(inputFileName)
    deck.SaveAs(outputFileName, formatType) # formatType = 32 for ppt to pdf
    deck.Close()
    powerpoint.Quit()

PPTtoPDF('07-20 contact PPT.pptx','./Reports/07-20 contact result',32)
```